# Is there a way to make git more verbose while pulling from a repo.?

Tags: git

I'm on debian. I'm using git to pull stuff from repositories. My git version is:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.2
```

I'm pulling from a remote repo, and my netspeed tells me it's downloading but my git pull is at a certain percentage. Let me share with an actual attempt:

```
$ git pull origin master --verbose
POST git-upload-pack (935 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 62, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (62/62), done.
Unpacking objects:  22% (14/62)
```

Now as can be seen, it's either stuck or is at 22% and the number will change only when it's 23%. Now is there a way to make it show something something like 22.10% and like that, so I can find in real-time what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the [`builtin/unpack-objects.c#unpack_all(void)`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b4f86a4ce85e4e370a67455de6586a02f158a789/builtin/unpack-objects.c#L467-L493) function calls [`display_progress()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b4f86a4ce85e4e370a67455de6586a02f158a789/progress.c#L191-L194) only for each object unpacked:

```
for (i = 0; i < nr_objects; i++) {
  unpack_one(i);
  display_progress(progress, i + 1);
}
```